# Java autocomplete messes up end of line typing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse (Java editor), when using autocomplete, I press End button on my keyboard to add a semicolon and finish up my line of code. What I end up with is the carret being placed at the end of line, but actually writing where the first attribute in a method call should be. What I end up is this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use autocomplete in two ways here:

1. Press `esc` twice and then press `end` button.
2. Press `enter` three time (for each parameter role, jobId and p_userName) and it will take you to the end with default parameter set as variables.

Comment: Seriously, there's no way to just type exactly where the cursor is actually blinking? I know about the esc way, but it's very annoying.